# Display recent wordpress posts on a page

Tags: wordpress

I would like to display all of the recent wordpress posts in a page on wordpress. I have tried  a few plugins with not much luck. I would simply like to display the title and excerpt of the last 10 posts. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create  recentpost.php and save it on the same directory with your current theme

This should be the basic content of your recentpost.php

```
//-------start here
<?php
/*
Template Name: Recent Post
*/
?>
<?php
 get_header();
?>

<h2>Recent Posts</h2>
<ul>
<?php
        $args = array( 'numberposts' => '10' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.$recent["post_title"].'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
    }
?>
</ul>

<?php
 get_sidebar();
 get_footer();
?>

//--------end here
```

And on your Admin Control page, create new page, and on the right side you can select the template "Recent Post".

Comment: That solution works great, I am wondering if it possible add a teaser of the articles? Like the first 20 words or something. Any thoughts on how I can do this?

Comment: You can add the excerpt after the title between </a></li> like this: "</a><br />$recent["post_excerpt"]</li>", you can add as many post information as you like, just add $recent["(information name here like post_title, psot_excerpt, etc)"] inside the for loop and inside the <li></li>.

Comment: Thanks Free Lancer. For some reason the post_excerpt wasn't working but I did have luck using post_content and limiting characters.

Comment: maybe, when you are creating your post, you don't fill up the excerpt in the post editor. Yes, limiting the content will do the trick. Glad that it work.

Answer (score 2):

This piece of code should display the title and excerpt of the last 10 post

```
<?php 
    $arguments = array('numberposts' => '10');
    $posts = wp_get_recent_posts($arguments);
    foreach($posts as $post){
        the_title();
        the_excerpt();
    }
?>
```